# How to calculate average in Excel for cells that are 102 rows apart?

Tags: excel

Consider the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
      A          B       C        D        E
   1  company  date    money    date    average
   2  1        03-14       6    03-14      4    (6 + 3 + 3) / 3
   3  1        03-15       2    03-15      6    (2 + 7 + 9) / 3
   4  1        03-16       5    03-16      3.33 (5 + 1 + 4) / 3
   5  1        03-17       1    03-17      5.67 (1 + 9 + 7) / 3
   6  2        03-14       3    .
   7  2        03-15       7    .
   8  2        03-16       1    08-05
   9  2        03-17       9
   10 3        03-14       3
   11 3        03-15       4
   12 3        03-16       4
   13 3        03-17       7
```

For `100` companies, I have a `money` value for each `date` between `03-14` and `08-05` (`102` days in total, because I removed the weekends and holidays; the above spreadsheet is a shortened example). The data is structured as panel data. In column `D` I have listed all the dates and in `E` I want to calculate the average `money`-value for each date (see example calculations).

My question is: with what Excel formula for column `E` could I accomplish this?

The `average` for `03-14` would be the `AVERAGE` of cell `D2 + D104 + D206 + ... D10202` (`102` cells apart), the `AVERAGE` for `03-15` would be calculated as the average of `D3 + D105 + D207 ... etc`.

Who knows how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which version of Excel are you using? In Excel 2007 or later you can use AVERAGEIF function, e.g. this formula in E2 copied down

`=AVERAGEIF(B:B,D2,C:C)`

In earlier versions of excel try SUMIF/COUNTIF like this

`=SUMIF(B:B,D2,C:C)/COUNTIF(B:B,D2)`

Comment: That's just awesome...wish I asked sooner, would have saved me about 2 hrs of my time. Thanks! (BTW for future reference, in Excel 2007 criteria are separated by `;`, so `=AVERAGEIF(B:B;D2;C:C)` worked perfectly)

Comment: No problem - The argument separator varies depending on your region - in the UK and US, for example, comma separators are used, I assume you are in Europe where mostly ; is used........